# Do I need to use specific CSS styles for JQuery autocomplete to work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm having an issue where none of the items in the results of the autocomplete query are selectable. I see this in the documentation, but most of the JQuery examples are not clear on whether or not the css styles matter.

> This widget requires some functional CSS, otherwise it won't work. If you build a custom theme, use the widget's specific CSS file as a starting point.

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Do I need to use specific CSS styles for JQuery autocomplete to work?

Comment: Do you have the jquery UI css referenced?

Comment: I do, but it's conflicting with my own css styles, so before I go down that path I'm wondering if they're needed.

Comment: Yeah they will be required for the placement of the layer that is showing once you start typing.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if they're required in order for the select to work?

Comment: Could be that the items are appearing below another element on your page, so even though they are visible, your click event is not actually on the element you think you clicking on

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a try.

Comment: No luck. Could be an issue with my _renderItem override or something.

Comment: @mstrom technically you do not need any CSS to have the autocomplete work. It will stil lrender the list elements and operate, it will just not be themed, no styling will be applied, and it will look strange. If you're encountering an issue, I would advise posting a snippet of your code or reviewing your console for errors. If there is a conflict between stylesheets, this can be corrected by adjusting the load order and importance.